# Can't load image to pygame display

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

My image won't show on the screen but I don't get any errors. I looked it up and found no solution that works for me.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
sw = 500
sh = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((sw,sh))
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
x = (sw * 0.3)
y = (sh * 0.95)
# also tried just convert() and no convert at all
player = pygame.image.load('SH.png').convert_alpha()
white = (255, 255, 255)
def Player(x, y):
    win.blit(player, (x, y))

dead = False

run = True
while not dead:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True
    win.fill(white)
    Player(x, y)

    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Does it work if you try a different image?

Comment: Works for me with my own image although the image is almost off the bottom of the window that's displayed. How big is your image? Suggest that you upload the image file you're using to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and then [edit] your question and add a link to it (because that sounds like it might be the issue).

Comment: My guess is that your image has a lot of empty/transparent space at the top and since you're blitting it near the bottom of the screen, it's not visible because the opaque area is below the screen. However, I can't verify that without your image, so please add it to the question.

Comment: i have figured it out. sorry for wasting time with this question :/

Answer (score 0):

I made the image smaller because it was too big and was off-screen.

This resolved the problem